# Trying to add launchtime and created date to aws cli query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am using the below query:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[]|.Instances[]|[(.Tags[]?|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value), (.Tags[]?|select(.Key=="Group-Name")|.Value),.InstanceId,.PrivateIpAddress]|@csv'|sort
```

Which outputs as follows:

```
"sit-test1-zoo-1","i-01205c55a999bebbf","10.153.XX.XXX"
"sit-test2-zoo-2","i-064167c876934448","10.153.XX.XXX"
```

But I wanted to slide in the date the instance was created and the launch date. I can't seem to figure out the expected syntax having put .Launchdate and .Created in various places within the command. Can anyone please help?

I have come up with the below that produces output (sadly, the same output) and I feel like this is a step in the direction I need to go in, but obvs it does not give the columns I want to see...

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[]|.Instances[] | select(.LaunchTime > "2015-01-28")|[(.Tags[]?|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value), (.Tags[]?|select(.Key=="Group-Name")|.Value),.InstanceId,.PrivateIpAddress,.Launchtime.Value]|@csv'|sort
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `LaunchTime` where you tried with `Launchtime`.

Here is the working query that will print launch time

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[]|.Instances[] | select(.LaunchTime > "2015-01-28")|[(.Tags[]?|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value), (.Tags[]?|select(.Key=="Group-Name")|.Value),.InstanceId,.PrivateIpAddress,.LaunchTime]|@csv'|sort
```

Output

```
"demo","i-1234","10.0.4.54","2020-02-24T10:25:48+00:00"
```

Also, I will suggest to use [jmespath-query](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/07/27/advanced-aws-cli-jmespath-query/) instead of `jq`, Here is the same output without sorting etc

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceId:InstanceId,LaunchTime:LaunchTime,Tags:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0],PrivateIpAddress:PrivateIpAddress}' --output table
```

Output

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                      DescribeInstances                                                     |
+---------------------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|     InstanceId      |        LaunchTime          | PrivateIpAddress  |                        Tags                         |
+---------------------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  i-1234234234dsf        |  2017-09-25T22:18:20+00:00 |  10.0.0.243       |  demp                                            |
```

[aws-cli-cheatsheet](https://github.com/Adiii717/aws-cli-cheatsheet)